# Messages in iCloud on some devices, mixed with old devices?

Tags: macos, ios, messages, messages-in-icloud

What is the behaviour if not all devices support Messages in iCloud?

Do the supported devices sync to iCloud and the older devices continue to receive messages as normal, not synced?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is exactly how it works. The devices that have **Messages in iCloud** enabled will sync amongst themselves, while older devices will keep working as they always did.

More precisely:

- iOS devices with Messages in iCloud will no longer backup messages as part of iCloud Backup. This means that their backups should be smaller.
- Devices that support Messages in iCloud will merge their messages with one another via iCloud, filling any “gaps” they may have had. Unsupported devices will neither merge their messages nor fill in any gaps they had.
- If you delete a message/conversation on a device that supports Messages in iCloud, it will be deleted from all devices that support Messages in iCloud. That message/conversation will remain on unsupported devices.
- Unsupported devices connected to your iCloud account will continue to receive iMessages just like before. There is no need for Messages in iCloud there.
- Unsupported devices setup for **SMS Forwarding** will continue to receive and be able to send SMS/MMS messages like normal. No need for Messages in iCloud there either.

Comment: thanks for the detailed answer. can you confirm that you have tested this yourself? any glitches?

Comment: Yes, that’s how it worked until I enabled it on all my devices. Honestly I’m not sure how else it *could* work. Just be patient while everything syncs; lots of people are updating and slamming Apple’s servers, sometimes with upwards of 10 GBs worth of messages. It’s recommended you keep your devices plugged in and connected to Wi-Fi while the sync is taking place, and run an iCloud Backup of your iOS devices once it’s done.